# How do I protect a TDataModule bound to a HTTP session against concurrent usage?

Tags: delphi, http, concurrency, indy

In my [Indy](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/index.html) (TIdHTTPServer) based web server application, every HTTP session has a separate TDataModule which will be created 'on demand':

```
procedure TExampleHTTPServer.OnHandleRequest(Request:
  TIdHTTPRequestInfo; Response: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
const
  KEY = 'datamodule';
var
  Pos: Integer;
  DM: TDemoDataModule;
  Tmp: string;
  S: string;
begin
  Request.Session.Lock;
  try
    Pos := Request.Session.Content.IndexOf(KEY);
    if Pos <> -1 then
    begin
      DM := TDemoDataModule(Request.Session.Content.Objects[Pos]);
    end
    else
    begin
      WriteLn(Format('Create datamodule for session %s',
       [Request.Session.SessionID]));
      DM := TDemoDataModule.Create(nil);
      Request.Session.Content.AddObject(KEY, DM);
    end;
  finally
    Request.Session.Unlock;
  end;
  ... // do something with the datamodule - this is the interesting part
```

So whenever a request is sent from the same client HTTP session, the server tries to find the datamodule in the session objects, and uses it (to store session specific data, execute database queries etc.). If there is no datamodule instance yet, the server creates it.

This works, however there is a risk of concurrent access: because the session is identified by a session token (stored in a cookie), it may happen that the same client opens two connections at the same time with the same session token, and so the server will receive two requests which both want to access the same datamodule.

For this reason, thread safe access to the datamodule instance is required.

I guess that the simplest solution is a TMonitor, so every access to the datamodule would be wrapped:

```
TMonitor.Enter(DM);
try
  DM.SomeProperty := AValue;
  ...
finally
  TMonitor.Exit(DM);
end;
```

Or am I missing some other, maybe more elegant, solution?

Comment: In my experience, web applications are stateless and any database queries are opened and closed everytime the page is accessed.

Comment: @penarthur66 I know that session state should be avoided in web applications. But not all web applications use a database back-end, many do not even need persistent data. So the datamodule could use TClientDataSet/TSomeInMemoryDataSet or simple TObjectList data containers.

Comment: Instead of making your data module block (and destroying web performance) why don't you move your minimal set of concurrent guards somewhere else?

Comment: @mjn yet your question specifically mentions "make database queries"....... But if you do not want to store persistent data why not use a cookie?

Comment: @penarthur66 from [a good read: Why are Facebook, Digg, and Twitter so hard to scale?](http://highscalability.com/blog/2009/10/13/why-are-facebook-digg-and-twitter-so-hard-to-scale.html): `Everything must be kept in RAM cache so that the data can be accessed as fast as possible.` - database queries would be too slow. I would not try to save the Facebook database in cookies (and update them continuously)

Comment: I will rewrite the question later. It is not TDataModule specific, *all* session-bound object could be 'in danger' of concurrent modification

Comment: @mjn Interesting, but with respect, if you're asking questions like this here, you're not going to be building a website the size of facebook. And you won't be building it in Delphi. I built many websites in Delphi 10+ years ago but would not even think about doing it today. C# is easy enough to learn and has a whole development environment that is much better for website development.